# How to prevent your free tier heroku app from idling(python/django)

Tags: python, django, heroku

Is there any way, through code, to prevent your app from idling? I'm thinking something like what is being done [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-prevent-your-free-heroku-dyno-from-sleeping-dggxo3bi2). How to do this through code, but in python/django as that is what my app is done in, i.e. what is the equivalent in python to Node's setInterval. What are the disadvantages of using a pinging service over doing it through code(other than if the site goes down your app wont get pinged). Can you recommend a good pinging service? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it from within the application. It needs to be woken up "externally". This can be just another Heroku application but that kind of defeats the purpose. There are some Heroku add ons that allow you to monitor your website thus also pinging it in regular intervals.

For example:
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/newrelic

With this your website would always stay awake.

The article you linked is imo more complicated than necessary. If you own a VPS you could host your website there. You could also write a `curl` command save it as a shell script and call it from cron (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).